# ASP.NET Webforms Routing gives 404 error

Tags: asp.net, webforms, url-routing

I have an issue with my project running on iis express.

In my routing table, routes are defined as:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("agl", "Agent/Login/", "~/_agent/Login.aspx")
routes.MapPageRoute("agd", "Agent/", "~/_agent/Default.aspx")
```

The problem is, when I type ***Agent/Login*** into the browser, the login page comes up as expected however, typing ***Agent/*** gives a 404 error.

I have googled and tried some web.config tweaks with no luck so I really would appreciate any possible solutions.

Comment: I think that your problem is not in routing configuration but somewhere else. Can you reproduce the same issue on a clean project?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I have tried this in two different PCs both not working as expected. I am still looking into this. Will post a comment when I resolve this..

Comment: @AlexanderManekovskiy Solved it: Click on the project name, F4 to bring up its properties and changed Managed Pipeline Mode from Integrated to Classic.. It works now :S

Comment: My bad. switching pipeline to classic did nothing at all and displayed an empty page (hence I thought this was fixed) In my case, it was another route causing the trouble.. e.g. routes.MapPageRoute("somepage", "{any-val-here}/", "~/SomePage.aspx") so when I thyped in Agent/ this route was catched beforehand and since SomePage.aspx did not exist, it gave me the 404 error.